# How to Ionic 2 swip tabs Or how can I like android tabss

Tags: ionic2

I want to do swipe tabs with an ionic 2, but I have not found anything I can do with. How I can do it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/ionic2/5569/using-tabs#t=201612102004352536268

Comment: The action on the link you give me is not working.